# How to traverse an XML document?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jdom

I am trying to browse a XML file with JDOM's the code to browse:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.jdom.*;
import org.jdom.input.*;
import org.jdom.filter.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class PremierJdom {

   static org.jdom.Document document;
   static Element racine;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      //On crée une instance de SAXBuilder
      SAXBuilder sxb = new SAXBuilder();
      try
      {
         //On crée un nouveau document JDOM avec en argument le fichier XML
         //Le parsing est terminé ;)
         document = sxb.build(new File("Example.wsdl"));
      }
      catch(Exception e){}

      //On initialise un nouvel élément racine avec l'élément racine du document.
      racine = document.getRootElement();
      //System.out.println(racine.getName());

      //Méthode définie dans la partie 3.2. de cet article
      afficheALL();
   }


//Ajouter cette méthodes à la classe JDOM2
static void afficheALL()
{
   //On crée une List contenant tous les noeuds "etudiant" de l'Element racine
   List listEtudiants = racine.getChildren("binding");

   //On crée un Iterator sur notre liste
   Iterator i = listEtudiants.iterator();
   while(i.hasNext())
   {
      //On recrée l'Element courant à chaque tour de boucle afin de

      Element courant = (Element)i.next();
      //On affiche le nom de l’élément courant
      System.out.println(courant.getAttributeValue("name"));

   }
}
}
```

But the problem that arises here is that when I execute this class I will have no output.
and here is the file `Example.wsdl`

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding= "UTF-8" ?> 
<definitions name= "Web Service Mediation"
 targetNamespace="http://these-info.univ-tun.com/Web Service Mediation " 
xmlns=" http://these-info.univ-tun.comstem online"
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"  > 

  <binding name="ConnTWSAlt" type="wsdlns:SimplePortType">
<soap:binding style="rpc" 
 transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="foo">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/action/binding.ConnTWSAlt"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded"  
 encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" 
encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
</output>
</operation>
</binding> 
</definitions>
```

Someone can help to correct this error.

Comment: English only please, even translating (or else not including) your comments would be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

You really, really, really should be using JDOM 2.x and not JDOM 1.x There are many reasons for this, including that JDOM 1.x is old, and no longer maintained. JDOM 2.x was released more than 3 years ago, and includes support for generics and so on. See [this list of new features](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/wiki/JDOM2-Features)

Using JDOM 2.x would also make your issue easier to see.

Right, your problem is that you are calling `getChildren(...)` without using a namespace:

> ```
>    //On crée une List contenant tous les noeuds "etudiant" de l'Element racine
>    List listEtudiants = racine.getChildren("binding");
> ```

That code says: get all child elements of  `racine` that are in the namespace with the URL `""`. What you want is to get child elements in the namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/` with the local name `binding`.

To do that, you need to get a `Namespace` instance in the correct URL, and use that for the getChildren call too:

Namespace soap = Namespace.getNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/");

.....

```
List listEtudiants = racine.getChildren("binding", soap);
```

Note that, in JDOM 2.x, that would be:

```
List<Element> listEtudiants = racine.getChildren("binding", soap);
```

and as a consequence, your current code:

> ```
> static void afficheALL()
> {
>
>    //On crée une List contenant tous les noeuds "etudiant" de l'Element racine
>    List listEtudiants = racine.getChildren("binding");
>
>    //On crée un Iterator sur notre liste
>    Iterator i = listEtudiants.iterator();
>    while(i.hasNext())
>    {
>       //On recrée l'Element courant à chaque tour de boucle afin de
>
>       Element courant = (Element)i.next();
>       //On affiche le nom de l’élément courant
>       System.out.println(courant.getAttributeValue("name"));
>
>    }
> }
> ```

should all be reduced down to:

```
private static final Namespace SOAP = Namespace.getNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/");

static void afficheALL()
{
   //On crée une List contenant tous les noeuds "etudiant" de l'Element racine
   for (Element courant : racine.getChildren("binding", SOAP))
   {
      //On affiche le nom de l’élément courant
      System.out.println(courant.getAttributeValue("name"));
   }
}
```

Comment: Some of us would say you really, really should be using DOM rather than any version of JDOM ...

Comment: @keshlam - that may be, but, as the maintainer of JDOM, you likely won't hear me saying that. Don't get me wrong, there are reasons to use DOM, but in this case, compare the logic above with what you would have to do in DOM.

Comment: Most of the examples I've seen that make jdom look better were clearly written by someone who didn't know how to use the DOM effectively. I haven't worked thru this one, but it looks like DOM level 2 can do it just about as easily, and more portably.